# How to turn off JS Bundling for ASP.NET ZERO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abp

I added a new js for my view. It's called `Edit.js`. When I check my console errors, it's looking for `Edit.min.js`. My question is two parts, how do I resolve this error so that Edit.min.js will be available? I've tried `npm run create-bundles` but the error `Edit.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` still persist.

I was also hoping to disable bundling while development so I can step through my javascript code.

Here's my[Gulpfile](https://plnkr.co/edit/ELufnwkDCsaxZTG9?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

I know my javascript is accessible if I go directly to the non minified js

```
http://localhost:5000/view-resources/Areas/AppAreaName/Views/Contacts/Edit.js
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `>I've tried npm run create-bundles but the error Edit.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) still persist.`
Can you please check if minified js file exist.(It is located in the same position of normal js)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `watchScriptEntries();` and `watchStyleEntries();` it wil stop watching hot changes. But you will need to rerun `npm run create-bundles` everytime you made some changes